# Is the Prometheus system compatible with Wanhao Duplicator i3 Plus?

Tags: wanhao, multi-material, duplicator-i3-plus

I'm trying to figure out whether the [Wanhao Duplicator i3 Plus](http://www.wanhao3dprinter.com/xiazai/I3_Plus_user_manual_REV.A.pdf) can easily be extended to print with two separate filaments using the [Prometheus System](https://www.distechautomation.com/products/prometheus-system) by DisTech Automation using a single hotend (NOT with two separate hot ends/nozzles).

According to DisTech, the Prometheus System is compatible with 3D printers that support the following:

- Dual extruder stepper motors on the controller board
- CURA slicer engine (Simplify3D support is in development)
- Marlin/Repetier based firmware (this includes almost all desktop 3D printers)

As I'm not an expert on 3D printing and don't own the Duplicator yet (making up purchase decision right now), I'd appreciate if you could help me with your past experience with Duplicator and/or Prometheus.

Comment: the Wanhao shop is down. I had to change to the manual of the printer.

Answer (score 3):

The Prometheus system is pretty much a Y-coupler and two extruders. So, you need your Wanhao Duplicator i3 Plus to have the connection points for two extruders and the axis, which means you need one free, 4 wire connection slot from a stepper driver. So, let's look what kind of board is in there...

[image: the Wanhao Duplicator i3+ Mainboard]

This Melzi Hypbrid is the mainboard the Duplicator uses, similar to a lot of other Melzi derivates (itself as it seems a Sanguino Derivate). The green 4-pin terminal is the extruder. There is only one of these. So it is not useable with Prometheus. You would need to get a mainboard that is able to run dual extruders.

Comment: Also note that although this board shows 2 connectors for the Z axis (Z1 and Z2), a connector cannot be sourced from here as they are controlled by the same stepper driver (they are connected in series).